# WMI namespace root\cimv2 not available on Win2k?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi, windows-2000

I'm trying to run the following VBScript code on a Win2k SP4:

```
strComputer = "."    
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

It works on XP and Win7 without problems, but on this 2k box I get the following error:

```
C:\test_wmi.vbs(3, 1) (null): 0x8004100E
```

The error description is: Namespace specified cannot be found.

When I query the namespaces on root, using this code:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root")
Set colNameSpaces = objSwbemServices.InstancesOf("__NAMESPACE")

For Each objNameSpace In colNameSpaces
 Wscript.Echo objNameSpace.Name
Next
```

I get this:

```
DEFAULT
SECURITY
WMI
directory
aspnet
```

As far as I have read, CIMV2 namespace should be there. Any ideas???

Thanks!

yorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, what worked for me was rebuilding the WMI Repository. This is what I did:

- Stop the WMI service (net stop winmgmt)
- Go to %windows%/system32/wbem (in my win2k, winnt, on XP would be windows)
- Rename or remove the repository directory
- Start the WMI service again (net start winmgmt)

Also, this method could have helped (to reinstall WMI into the Registry):

```
winmgmt /clearadap
winmgmt /kill
winmgmt /unregserver
winmgmt /regserver
winmgmt /resyncperf
```

Thanks Uros for your help, both webcasts and the tool were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was on Windows Server 2003, Service Pack 2, and yorch's solution didn't work for me. Finally I found this page, and followed the instructions for Server 2003:

http://www.djordjepejic.com/kb68/index.php/article/winmgmt-could-not-initialize-the-core-parts-solved-even/

> For Windows Server 2003
>   Use the following command to detect and repair a corrupted WMI Repository:
>
> `rundll32 wbemupgd, RepairWMISetup`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be there. There is a tool called [wmidiag.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d7ba3cd6-18d1-4d05-b11e-4c64192ae97d&displaylang=en) that can help you diagnose WMI problems, but before using it try watching a couple of 'webcasts' that explain how to use it ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/detail/webcastdetails.aspx?seriesid=88&webcastid=312) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/detail/webcastdetails.aspx?seriesid=6&webcastid=1470))

Comment: Thanks, very interesting webcasts and a very handy tool, but when I ran the WMIDiag tool, I got the same response (Namespace specified cannot be found) and no suggested solution for that.