# How to make a script run only while another one is running

Tags: powershell

I need your help resolving an exercise in Powershell.
I have to make a script which runs only when another one is running.
For example, I have to run a script which deletes files older than 1 day while a script which restarts a process runs.

I tried to use jobs to make the script run in parallel but I haven't had any succes.

```
--The script to delete files
Get-ChildItem -Path "a path" -include *.txt -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateToDelete} | Remove-Item -Force

--The script to restart a process
Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process | Start-Process
```

Comment: why you had no luck using job? do you mean you don't want to use it? or you didn't figure out how to use it?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it. I can run the script which restarts a process, but the other one is not working.

Comment: what is the value of `$DateToDelete` ?

Comment: $Days = "-1"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Days)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the second script, you can't restart a process like that.

If you tried this line `Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process | Start-Process` in the console it will prompt you requesting the `FilePath` to the process you want to start, that's because `Stop-Process` do not return any result to the pipeline and then `Start-Process` is not receiving anything from the pipeline.

Look here to see [how to restart process using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091345/stop-and-then-start-a-process-in-powershell)

And take a look at this [MS module Restart-Process](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Restart-Process-ee3290c1)

Use this code to run scripts as job:

```
$days = -1
$currentDate = Get-Date
$DateToDelete = $currentDate.AddDays($days)

start-job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "a path" -include *.txt -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateToDelete} | Remove-Item -Force
}

start-job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process
}
```

Comment: You can install the module using Powershell `Install-Module Restart-Process`